# Django template namespace

Tags: django, django-templates

I read that for every app of my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`, Django will look for HTML templates inside the `templates` subdirectory. But I'm a little confused.

For instance, when creating my HTML templates in the initial project below:

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        templates/
```

Should I simply create a `template` subdirectory within the `myapp` directory and put all my HTML templates inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, the templates subdirectory within `myapp` also needs `myapp` subdirectory which will contain all of your app html files. Also do not mix core project files such as `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` within app, better separate them out, hence the better structure would be:

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        wsgi.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        templates/myapp/
```

Comment: But is not this redundant? Because "templates/" is already a subdirectory of "myapp/"...

Comment: This is because it meshes well with the app-directories template loader. Templates inside app is usually used for re-usable apps or personal preference, so if someone else wants to override your template the user just has to create a folder in templates directory with same app name to overview some or all of your app html files.

Comment: You can read more about how [app_directories Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) works. (correction for previous comment, i meant: overview -> override)

Comment: Should `mysite/` have a `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes it will have `__init__.py` obviously.